# pinch zoom feature inside a scroll view

Tags: android, pinchzoom

I have a scroll view. I need to apply pinch zoom feature inside this scroll view. Can any suggest a method? Is there any library to include a container view having pinch zoom feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got the solution. Let me share that.

https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/w/list using this library we can create a zoomview and we can add other views to it.

There is no wiki page associated with this project so please check this [Wiki about android-zoom-view.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254076/wiki-about-android-zoom-view-jar)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a custom ImageView with pinch zoom ability.
Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458910/2511775 . It's one of the best answers I've found on SO.

Comment: It is not a case of an imageview. I need to pinch zoom a scrollview containg imageview,buttons etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work properly in scrollview. ["issue"](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/issues/157)