# TouchImageView is not scrolling inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, zooming, touchimageview

I have view pager in the ScrollView which contain the TouchImageView, i want to zoom and scrolling image. it's not scrolling when i touch the ImageView. my code is look like below please help me guys!

```
<com.ui.widget.TouchImageView
 android:id="@+id/img_item"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
 android:src="@drawable/img_girl1"/>
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20673915/3514144

Comment: here ZoomView is extend FrameLayout instead i' loading image in imageview using image Fetcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is very delicate. As TouchImageView is a custom widget, it may not have been dealt with NestedScrollView. Use PhotoViewAttacher to your ImageView and see if this works.

Add this to dependency in the app gradle:

```
 dependencies {
  compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
}
```

In Java Class:

```
PhotoViewAttacher pAttacher;
pAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(Your_Image_View);
pAttacher.update();
```

And then Attach your ImageView inside the NestedScrollView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

           //Add ImageView Here

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: then, use it inside the ObservableScrollView. It may work who knows ?! :p

Comment: yeah it's scrolling smoothly but now image is not zooming properly

Comment: Is it lagging or something ?

Comment: actually it's not zooming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136017/discussion-between-komal-and-tahsinrupam).

Comment: yeah Thank You so much it's working for me but here no need top add
PhotoViewAttacher pAttacher;
pAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(Your_Image_View);
pAttacher.update();

Comment: then how r you using photoView to your image?

Answer (score 1):

Use This CustomScrollview and place TouchyImageview inside it

```
  public class CustomView extends ScrollView { 

   @Override
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);    
    return mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev); 
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
    ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // Handle the scale..
            return true;
        }
   }
}
```

Try This Scollview Instead Of Widget Scrollview here i remove the  override  onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouchEvent methods of scrollview