# Handle pinch zoom on recylerview

Tags: android

I want to achieve pinch, zoom on a recylerview. I have some text views in recylerview. I would like to change text size on the pinch. I successfully handle, pinch on an empty activity using Pinch zoom for a custom view. But it is not working on recylerview. Recylerview just scroll instead of pinch event. I handled separate touch event on textview but not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this. You can use this library https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/downloads/list . This library will allow you to zoom recylerview like an image. You can change this library to your needs. 
There is no wiki page associated with this project so check this [Wiki about android-zoom-view.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254076/wiki-about-android-zoom-view-jar)